# Error PLS-00201 while trying to create table type in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, types, oracle19c

When I run this code in Oracle 19c:

```sql
CREATE TYPE t_my_type IS TABLE OF my_table.my_col%TYPE;
```

I have this error:

```
Type t_my_type compiled

LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
0/0       PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
1/23      PLS-00201: identifier 'my_table.my_col' must be declared
Errors: check compiler log
```

Why does it says that it must be declared?

Comment: You can use %type and %rowtype only in pl/sql objects. So you can define your type in a plsql package for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer here: https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/3582858/pls-00201-when-declaring-table-type

You can't use `%TYPE` in this case. You must use some predefined Oracle type like `NUMBER` or create a collection.

Example:

```sql
CREATE TYPE t_my_type IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```